# Rails: Find model with less than X associations, also including the ones without any

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to make a way to group our users into segments.

User model:

```
Class User
has_many :orders
```

Order model:

```
Class Order
has_many :orders
```

Now let's say that I want to make a segment of users who have made less than 5 orders.

```
User
.joins('left outer join orders on users.id = orders.user_id')
.group(:user_id)
.having('count(user_id) <= ?' 5)
```

However this just grabs the users that have at least 1 order. What do I need to do to also include users who don't have any orders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself. "eager_load" includes everything.

User.eager_load(:orders).group("users.id").having("count(orders.id) >= ?", 5)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this so try this and let me know.

```
User.joins( :orders ).group( 'users.id' ).having( 'count( order_id ) < 5' )
```

I believe you are counting the wrong column. you should count the `order_id`. Feel free to comment, if I am wrong or if this throws any error.

Comment: Didn't work.

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "order_id" does not exist
LINE 1: ...d" = "users"."id" GROUP BY users.id HAVING count( order_id )